# Joomla: multiple joomola sites under 1 domain/1 installation of joomla?

Tags: joomla, subdomain, joomla1.6

Basically I am wondering if i can have 1 main site (e.g. 'www.mysite.com') with one look/template applied and articles associated with that site, then a completely different site with a different look/different articles for a sub domain 'www.mysite.com/someotherpage'

Is this possible? and if so is it possible under 1 installation of joomla or will I have to install and setup joomla for every new sub domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you simply want to have a different design for different menu items or do you actually want to have two completely seperate sites? Because you can assign different templates to different menu items and in Joomla 1.6/1.7, you can even have the same template but with different parameter sets.

Answer (score 4):

Its possible..i have done before. i have refer following thinks for that site.i hope following links are more useful to you.[Link1](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites)
[Link2](http://docs.joomla.org/Multiple_Domains_and_Web_Sites_in_a_single_Joomla!_installation)

All the Best ..
With Regards,
R.Ram kumar.